# MVC3 - direct link in email to start controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, routes

I have a MVC3 app and I want to start an action directly with a link sent in an email.

The link looks like this

```
http://localhost:52972/Account/Confirm/c4e80acb46R8uIq
```

In my MVC app I have an AccountController  and I created an action Confirm, as below:

```
public ActionResult Confirm(string id)
{
    ViewBag.ConfirmMessage = id;
    return View();       
}
```

My route on global.asax is default one,

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

When I try to access the link, instead of going to the controller's action, I get the error

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure your website still running on port 52972?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your time
The actual issue was the param string was more complex that what I posted (I shortend it for simplicity in my post)

However, the real param I guess triggered some other different route (or maybe additional params, who knows)
I fixed the issue by converting the param to hex string (so it only contained 0-9, a-f) and then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller and Route look correct so my guess that your application is not running or running on a different port. Ensure in your system tray that you see the ASP.NET Development Server running, if not press F5 or ctrl+F5 (without debugging) to start it. Optionally you can set a specific port for your app by following this post : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is hosted in a virtual directory I suspect that you forgot the application name. So instead of:

```
http://localhost:52972/Account/Confirm/c4e80acb46R8uIq
```

the link must be:

```
http://localhost:52972/MyApplicationName/Account/Confirm/c4e80acb46R8uIq
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1-) Your server may down.
2-) Your port may be changed
3-) Your view does not exist.


solutions.

1-) Start your app again :)
2-) Set your application port as static from;
 Properties->Web->Servers Specific Port

3) Add new view
```